# Trying to implement a Play/Pause function on the same button for my voice recorder

Tags: java, android

I've been searching stackoverflow for an answer relevant to my problem but haven't found anything thus far. Here is a snippet of my code, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with my onClick method in onCreate as I'm reletively new to Java.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    duration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.audioDuration);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

    outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startRecording();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    stopRecording();
                    seekbar.clearAnimation();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

        }
    });
} 
    public void playRecording(View view){
    try{
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    durationHandler.postDelayed(updateSeekBarTime, 100);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playing Audio..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple to do it - Just add a `play.setText("Play/Pause")`. For your code, you can do this -

```
final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
boolean isPlaying = false;
play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
        if (isPlaying) {
           play.setText("Pause");
           isPlaying = false;
           //ADD CODE TO PAUSE HERE
        } else {
           play.setText("Play");
           isPlaying = true;
           //ADD CODE TO PLAY HERE
        }
    }
});
```

Any questions then ask. Also, if this works for you, please mark this answer as `selected`.

Comment: Thanks man, it works perfectly. Although my app crashes when I try resume after pause, but I should be able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on right track you can put boolean field on your class and check it if it is playing like this.

```
public void onClick(View view){
      if(playing){
        //pause
        playing = false;
      }
      else{
        //play
        playing = true;
      }
}
```